# How to update directed graph dynamically in d3js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm trying to update a directed graph dynamically, and trying to make the graph look like below after running the function "demo()" which calls the function "graph(data)" every 2 seconds (every 2 seconds a new node and link gets created). [image: Desired outcome]

My result is looking like this below:
[image]

The function "graph(data)" gets called where data is in format [dummy,dummy2]

```
graph(['P1', 'T1']);
  await sleep( 2000);

graph(['T1', 'P2']);
  await sleep( 2000);
```

**rules.push(data);**
adds incoming data to the array that makes up the nodes.

The code can be seen below:

```js
var rules = [];
var width, height,  svg;
width = 960;
height = 500;
svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
svg.append("svg:defs").append("svg:marker").attr("id", "arrow").attr("viewBox", "0 0 10 10").attr("refX", 0).attr("refY", 5).attr("markerUnits", "strokeWidth").attr("markerWidth", 8).attr("markerHeight", 6).attr("orient", "auto").append("svg:path").attr("d", "M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z");


function graph(data){
var width, height,  map, tasks, links, nodes, tick, radius, force, link, node;
width = 960;
height = 500;

rules.push(data);
console.log(rules);
map = d3.map();
rules.forEach(function(rule){
map.set(rule[0], {
fixed: false
});
return map.set(rule[1], false);
});
map.set(rules[0][0], {
fixed: true,
x: 100,
y: height / 2
});
map.set(rules[rules.length-1][0], {
fixed: true,
x: width / 2 - 100,
y: height / 2
});
tasks = map.keys();
links = rules.map(function(rule){
return {
source: tasks.indexOf(rule[0]),
target: tasks.indexOf(rule[1])
};
});
nodes = tasks.map(function(k){
var entry;
entry = {
name: k
};
if (map.get(k).fixed) {
entry.fixed = true;
entry.x = map.get(k).x;
entry.y = map.get(k).y;
}
return entry;
});


tick = function(){
var arrowheadLength = 8, // from markerWidth
  nodeRadius = 10;
link.each(function(d) {
var x1 = d.source.x,
    y1 = d.source.y,
    x2 = d.target.x,
    y2 = d.target.y,
    angle = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
d.targetX = x2 - Math.cos(angle) * (nodeRadius + arrowheadLength);
d.targetY = y2 - Math.sin(angle) * (nodeRadius + arrowheadLength);
});
link.selectAll("line").attr("x1", function(d){
return d.source.x;
}).attr("y1", function(d){
return d.source.y;
}).attr("x2", function(d){
return d.targetX;
}).attr("y2", function(d){
return d.targetY;
}).attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");
node.attr("transform", function(d){
return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
});

};
radius = d3.scale.sqrt().range([0, 6]);
force = d3.layout.force().size([width / 2, height]).charge(-100).linkDistance(function(d){
return 40;
});
force.nodes(nodes).links(links).on("tick", tick).start();
link = svg.selectAll(".link").data(links).enter().append("g").attr("class", "link");
link.append("line").style("stroke-width", 1).attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");
node = svg.selectAll(".node").data(nodes).enter().append("g").attr("class", "node").call(force.drag);
node.append("circle").attr("r", 10).style("fill", "blue");
node.append("text").attr("dy", ".35em").attr("text-anchor", "middle").text(function(d){
return d.name;
}).style("fill", "white");
console.log("HERE2");
console.log("HERE5");
}

function sleep(ms) {
return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function demo() {
graph(['P1', 'T1']);
  await sleep( 2000);

graph(['T1', 'P2']);
  await sleep( 2000);

graph(['T1', 'P3']);
  await sleep( 2000);

graph(['P2', 'T2']);
  await sleep( 2000);

graph(['P3', 'T2']);
  await sleep( 2000);

graph(['T2', 'P4']);


}

demo();
```

```html
<html>
<head><title>Hello</title>
<style>

.link line {
  stroke: #696969;
}

.link line.separator {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.node circle {
   border-radius: 50rem;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


</html>
```

I would appreciate your help for obtaining a result as shown on the first image.
Thanks in advance.